# Playa: Future Entries Not Showing

Tags: playa

I wish to show future 'events' on a page.  I have a channel, that contains a playa field that I use to associate the desired events.

I cannot seem to get it to show on the site.  I'm convinced it must be something simple that I am overlooking, but I can't figure out why it won't work.  Anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong? :(

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="isp" limit="1" show_future_entries="yes" dynamic="no"}
    {events show_future_entries="yes"}
        {title}
    {/events}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Apologies, missed the reference to Playa.

Comment: Are these unusual statuses or any such thing?  Also, if you output a title for the outer channel entries tag, do you get anything? I'd like to make sure you're getting results from that tag before further troubleshooting.

Comment: Have you tried the playa:children tag pair in place of the fieldtype tag pair?

Comment: You should check if channel entry tag is outputting correct entry as you are having limit as 1 and show_future_entries as "yes".

Comment: You've probably already looked at this, but could it be the Channel field Group setting of "Show future entries?" in your Playa field?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your issue?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you are using Structure or native EE templating, but a sure way to remedy this is to make sure your outer `channel:entries` tag is actually pulling the playa:parent page.

```
{!-- Replace XX with the parent page's entry_id --}
{exp:channel:entries channel="isp" entry_id="XX"}
    {events show_future_entries="yes"}
        {title}
    {/events}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```